# How to filter MongoDB documents which has a comma as part their string?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

has I have document something like,

```
[{"_id":"5f60d2033ccb5e2e08ff28b0", 
"account":"Option1, Option2, Option 3",  
}, 
{"_id":"5f60cc9946c66a58d08e95e9", 
"account":"Option4", 
}, 
{"_id":"5f60cc9946c66a58d08e07h8", 
"account":"Option5,Option6", 
},
{"_id":"5f60cc9946c66a58d08e48d3", 
"account":"Option7", 
}]
```

I would like to filter the documents which has comma separated string values for account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2DowiH1_Q-m)

```
db.collection.find({
  "account": {
    $regex: ".*,.*"
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind telling me the significance of ".*" here as without the ".*" also results in the same output? 

I can't find an answer for this, which I understand, in Google.

Comment: You don't need that. But it's best practice to add start and end markers. In that case, you need  `. *`